# Querying table where parent-child relation is the PK and FK in same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I use SQL Server and T-SQL and have a `Company` table like so:

| Id | Name | ParentId | Provider |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Name 1 | NULL | Provider 1 |
| 2 | Name 2 | NULL | Provider 2 |
| 3 | Name 3 | 2 | Provider 2 |
| 4 | Name 4 | 2 | Provider 2 |
| 5 | Name 5 | NULL | Provider 3 |
| 6 | Name 6 | NULL | NULL |
| 7 | Name 7 | NULL | NULL |
| 8 | Name 8 | 7 | NULL |
| 9 | Name 9 | 7 | NULL |
| 10 | Name 10 | NULL | Provider 4 |

I need to create a report displaying this:

| Billing | Provider | TopLevel | Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Provider 1 | Provider 1 | NULL | Name 1 |
| Provider 2 | Provider 2 | Name 2 | Name 2 |
| Provider 2 | Provider 2 | Name 2 | Name 3 |
| Provider 2 | Provider 2 | Name 2 | Name 4 |
| Provider 3 | Provider 3 | NULL | Name 5 |
| Name 6 | NULL | NULL | Name 6 |
| Name 7 | NULL | Name 7 | Name 7 |
| Name 7 | NULL | Name 7 | Name 8 |
| Name 7 | NULL | Name 7 | Name 9 |
| Provider 4 | Provider 4 | NULL | Name 10 |

So I want the `Billing` column to show:

- If `Provider IS NOT NULL`, use `Company.Provider`
- If `Provider IS NULL AND ParentId IS NULL`, use `Company.Name`
- If `Provider IS NULL AND ParentId IS NOT NULL`, use parent `Company.Name`

TopLevel

- If TopLevel is NULL, value should be NULL
- If TopLevel is not NULL, use parent Company.Name for both parent and child

At this point I am very stuck and sort of lost on where to go due to trying various ways to solve it which have just made things very confusing and chaotic in my mind.

I have tried left joining company table on itself, but that doesn't work since I don't get results in the same column.

I've also tried to use Case to get the values right.

The main problem is getting the TopLevel to also have the name of the parent for the parent as well when it's a parent-child relationship since the ParentID is a FK to the Id which is PK in the same table.

I've tried to look into CTE, but I am not sure if that's the correct way. I am also not familiar with CTE. Is Pivot what I should look into instead?

I don't mind being pointed to the correct material to read up on how to solve this, so I can learn more.

Any help would be appreciated at this point. Both a possible solution or tips on what to read up on to solve it.

I am not pressed for time on this as I solved in a different way which gave the person who needed the report what they needed, but I'd like to learn how to attack problems like these for the future when what I did might not work next time and just to know how to do it to get the result as I wanted.

Here is what I ended up doing to create a report that could be used, but isn't how I wanted it to be:

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN companyAlias.Provider IS NULL 
            THEN ''
            ELSE companyAlias.Provider
    END AS "Provider",     
    CASE
        WHEN (SELECT name FROM Companies 
              WHERE Id = companyAlias.ParentId) IS NOT NULL 
            THEN (SELECT name FROM Companies 
                  WHERE Id = companyAlias.ParentId)
            ELSE companyAlias.name
    END AS "BillingCompany",
    companyAlias.name,
FROM
    Companies companyAlias
```

Comment: Can rows be recursively associated (grandchildren)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `LEFT JOIN` companies again and then check with `COALESCE` the names or provider

```
SELECT
COALESCE(c1.[Provider],c2.[Name],c1.[name]) as billing,
  COALESCE(c1.[Provider],'') as Provider,
  COALESCE(c2.name,(SELECT TOP 1 c1.name FROM Companies c3 WHERE c3.[ParentId] = c1.[ID])) toplevel,
  COALESCE(c2.[Name],c1.[Name]) Name1,
  c1.Name
FROM Companies  c1 LEFT JOIN Companies  c2 ON c1.[ParentId] = c2.[Id]
```

| billing | Provider | toplevel | Name1 | Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Provider 1 | Provider 1 | *null* | Name 1 | Name 1 |
| Provider 2 | Provider 2 | Name 2 | Name 2 | Name 2 |
| Provider 2 | Provider 2 | Name 2 | Name 2 | Name 3 |
| Provider 2 | Provider 2 | Name 2 | Name 2 | Name 4 |
| Provider 3 | Provider 3 | *null* | Name 5 | Name 5 |
| Name 6 |  | *null* | Name 6 | Name 6 |
| Name 7 |  | Name 7 | Name 7 | Name 7 |
| Name 7 |  | Name 7 | Name 7 | Name 8 |
| Name 7 |  | Name 7 | Name 7 | Name 9 |
| Provider 4 | Provider 4 | *null* | Name 10 | Name 10 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/rDFpkOa_)

Comment: I am going to try this! Thank you! Will report back how it works out. :)

Comment: This is very nice. It solves the Billing column. Now I just have to find out how to make TopLevel Column as I want. 

I am overthinking this probably, because I am thinking I have to do like a search to check if the Id is not a parent. So I have to search through everything and make sure it doesn't exist as a ParentId. That sounds like a heavy SQL (performance vice) and not a very clever way of doing it.

Comment: Need to play with this tomorrow. Maybe use of Case and the EXIST/NOT EXIST can do the trick. That's the path I'm heading down now at least.

Comment: i have added the toplevel to the query

Comment: I have so much to learn.. So simple compared to what I was thinking. Thank you so much for the help.

Answer (score 1):

you can simply use COALESCE for these rules:

- If Provider IS NOT NULL, use Company.Provider
- If Provider IS NULL AND ParentId IS NULL, use Company.Name
- If Provider IS NULL AND ParentId IS NOT NULL, use parent Company.Name

```
SELECT
COALESCE(Company.Provider, Company.ParentID, Company.Name) AS yourColumn
FROM  Companies
```

Coalesce will always take first non-null value, so the order is important!

Comment: This is great, too. It will give me a mix of names and IDs, but I can just use it to get only the IDs and then map it to names in SQL. I will remember this, because this will get handy some other time. Thank you. :)